# How to print multiple columns without truncating?

Tags: bash, files, string, columns, truncate

I know that `pr -m -t file1 file2` will give me 2 columns like so:

file1:

```
a
abc
abcdefg
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

file2:

```
1
123
12345678
12345678901234567890
```

-

```
$ pr -m -t file1 file2
a                   1
abc                 123
abcdefg                 12345678
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghi 12345678901234567890
```

Above is a literal cut and paste, but here I added spaces to show how it really lines up in the terminal:

```
$ pr -m -t file1 file2
a                                   1
abc                                 123
abcdefg                             12345678
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghi 12345678901234567890
```

For some reason, `unix` stack exchange doesn't make the code blocks solid.
Anyway, I don't need the line numbers to match up (but to answer the general question, you could also answer how to do that) but the main property I want is to make it so that the lines wrap instead of getting truncated. Do I have no choice but to preprocess each file to a certain width and pipe that in? If so, how would I even do that?

Update: I suppose if there was some `command` which restricted the width of a file and forced wrapping into new lines, I'd do: `pr -m -t <(command file1) <(command file2)`

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Do you want something like `paste file1 file2` or `paste file1 file2 | column -t`?

Comment: Or adding a `-J` to your `pr` command (to join full lines and not truncate)

Comment: I suspect the misalignment on posting is because pr uses tabs. In your terminal they expand to 8-column format, but the forum expands tabs to 4-column format. I paste my terminal text through xed, which expands tabs and does block indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Care about alignment?

If you take the perl script found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505390/1212583), written by [Peter Stuifzand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633/peter-stuifzand), and were to name it `columnFix.perl` and `chmod u+x columnFix.perl` (to be sure you can execute it, you can do this:

```
pr -J -m -t file1 file2 | /path/to/columnFix.perl
```

---

**Original answer:**

The versions of `pr` I have truncate lines by default to 72 characters, with 2 columns that cuts the first column to 35 `(35 char/column * 2 columns) + 1 char/separator = 71 characters` (so the second column is possibly 36 characters).

So the same command you've run but with a `-J` should do what you seem to be looking for (with as close to your original command as possible) if you are fine with **no column alignment** (this is a similar result to the paste command suggested in comments)

`pr -J -m -t file1 file2`

From the man page:

> -J, --join-line
>
> merge full lines, turns off -W line truncation, **no column alignment**, --sep-string[=STRING] sets separators